# Chmoding a series of files bash script

Tags: bash, file, shell, chmod

I have faced this question and looking for the possible solution(s):

Write a bash script to run the command `chmod 644` on the files `/tmp/test28`, `/tmp/test29` ... up to `/tmp/test48`, except for `/tmp/test32`

And where may I find related exercises? Looking for resources, if possible please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the seq command.  Using your example above this code would do all except /tmp/test32

```
 for X in `seq 28 48`
 do
    if [ ${X} -ne 32 ]
    then
       touch /tmp/test${X}
    fi
done
```

Of course you will want to change touch command to chmod command as appropriate.  I just didn't have all those files so used touch to create them really quickly. What sort of resources are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As the only variation is the number, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=28;i<=48;i++));do
   ((i!=32)) && chmod 644 /tmp/test"$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this bash loop:

`for i in {28..48}; do
    if [[ ${i} -ne 32 ]]; then
        chmod 644 /tmp/test${i}
    fi
done`

If this was the real world, I would use a find command similar to this:
`find -name 'test*' ! -name 'test32' -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 644`

The find command would find all test* files, ignore test32, and print them to stdout separated by nulls.  The xargs -r0 says to read a list of files that is null-terminated, and the -r says only to run if there is at least one file.